# Adobe analytics API - Can you combine multiple segments in one report call?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a report in the Adobe Analytics UI which is segmented by 3 segments.
I'm trying to mimic this report using the Adobe Analytics API (v2).
I was able to successfully execute the report using the /report endpoint while applying a single segment with the globalFilters property.
However I'm not seeing any indication that you can apply more then one segment per report.

**Is there any way to execute a report with multiple segments via the API?**

Here is the link to the report documentations

```
https://www.adobe.io/apis/experiencecloud/analytics/docs.html#!AdobeDocs/analytics-2.0-apis/master/reporting-guide.md
```

For reference, an example of the request data of a successful report with a single segment I was able to execute:

```
{"rsid": "{rsid}", 
"globalFilters": [{"dateRange": "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000/2020-03-25T23:59:59.999", "type": "dateRange"},
 {"type": "segment", "segmentId": "{segmentId}"}],
 "dimension": "variables/lasttouchchannel",
 "metricContainer": {"metrics": [{"columnId": "Cart Additions", "id": "metrics/visits"}], "metricFilters": []},
 "settings": {"limit": 250, "dimensionSort": "asc", "page": 0}}
```

Please let me know if more information is needed,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kinda depends on what you want your report to ultimately look like vs. the actual segment definitions, but you can also apply segments in the `metricContainer.metricFilters[n]` and `rowContainer.rowFilters[n]` array objects level.

Comment: Interesting! 
Also not really documented, other than in the Swagger
 I'm not seeing any mentions of a rowContainer.

Do you have any insights on how the rowContainer works?
I'm going to try with the metricFilters first, see if does the trick

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have anything other than their Swagger and github docs to look at, either. Except.. one thing I do to get an idea of what I need to do is I login to AA and go to Workspaces and build the report I want. Then in the workspace level menu, I go to Help > Enable debugger. Then, when I hover over a given component (e.g. a freeform table), where the gear icon, expand arrow, and X are on the top right, there is now a bug icon. If you click on it, an overlay slides up showing the JSON payload(s) used to build the component, which is the same API 2.0 payload(s)

Comment: Here is doc entry talking about the debugger. The video mostly explains it same, but is kind of old (e.g. they've since added it as a menu item to enable instead of having to open js console put js code in) https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics-learn/tutorials/apis/using-analysis-workspace-to-build-api-2-requests.html?lang=en#apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can add multiple segments under global filters.
Simply add them to the 'globalFilters' parameter.

e.g.

```
{"rsid": "{rsid}", 
"globalFilters": [
{"dateRange": "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000/2020-03-25T23:59:59.999", "type":"dateRange"},
 {"type": "segment", "segmentId": "{segmentId}"},  {"type": "segment", "segmentId": "{segmentId2}"}],
 "dimension": "variables/lasttouchchannel",
 "metricContainer": {"metrics": [{"columnId": "Cart Additions", "id": "metrics/visits"}], "metricFilters": []},
 "settings": {"limit": 250, "dimensionSort": "asc", "page": 0}}
```

You can also add them under metricContainer.metricFilters[n] as suggested by Crayon Violent in the comments (thanks for the tips!), but I'm not sure if the results would be the same.

Ultimately 'globalFilters' gave me the results I was looking for and that is the solution I want with.